# How to force www with Traefik

Tags: .htaccess, docker, traefik

Ive been learning Traefik to use as a reverse proxy for various Wordpress sites Im running in Docker containers on a server. Currently I have 2 domains setup with Wp on the same ip and are working correctly.

Im having problems getting the domains to redirect to www so right now at http://example.com it just shows 'Index of' I have tried forcing a redirection via htaccess but this isnt working so Im assuming theres something I have to do in the Traefik settings?

This is my docker-compose.yml file but Ive only included the important parts here:

```
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Træfik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

wp-web2:
    container_name: cowork-wp
    image: wordpress:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql-db-cowork
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: foo
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: foo
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: passwd123
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db-cowork
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com"
      - "traefik.frontend.forcehost:www.example.com"
      #- "traefik.frontend.rule=Path: /"
    volumes:
      - ./src-tdm:/var/www/html
```

As you can see in the labels Ive been trying different Hosts as well as 'forcehost' but none of these seemed to have worked.

And this is the toml file:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

#Define Docker Backend Configuration
[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "example.com"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = true
```

and finally this is my force www rewrite rule from .htaccess

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer inspection of the documents shows that the different domains need to be defined with commas in the frontend Host: argument, eg:

```
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:www.example.com, example.com"
```